# how to generate Release build for IOS..?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Android Release Build Successfully Done from My Side, But I Don't Know About how to generate build for IOS

Android `gradlew` `assembleRelease` is `sucessfully` done from my side

IOS Release Build and submit on App store.

Comment: Hello, did you generate your provisional profile from the apple developer account?

Comment: Yes I have App Store Account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please follow the below URL and let me know if any issue.

1) Create required IOS certificates from here:
https://apiko.com/blog/deploying-react-native-apps-to-app-store-and-play-market/

2) Create release build with following steps:

1. Go to edit schema and change debug to release and uncheck all the checked for debug
2. Clean the build folder.
3. Run below command for create a bundle
   "  react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios "
4. Go to xcode >> General please make sure you have selected same profile in signing(Release).
5. Select "Generic IOS device" and from top header click on Product >> Archive.
6. When you successfully build you need to next and on the next step you need to select your provisional profile and certificate.
7. On the last step you will see an option to export the build please select "export" and save your build on the local machine.
8. Now search for application loader from the mac and choose your release build once you complete all the steps.
9. Check at  below app store URL
   https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app

After 5-15 min you'll have an option on app store Build section with the plus(+) icon. Click on it and select your build, complete the form and submit your app.

Comment: I am happy to help you.

Comment: my build is of different size as it should and crashes as soon as i tap on it. in xcode 13.

Comment: You installed debug build right? Please make sure you have added your iPhone UDID in apple developer account and add that into provisioning profile and install it again.

Answer (score 6):

The following assumes that you are on mac os, the js dependencies are downloaded and that your ios native part is in the subdirectory ios

**With Pods**

- Download the ios dependencies: From the `ios/` directory in you repo execute `pod install`
- Open the xcodeworkspace (in the ios subdirectory) in xcode

**Without Pods**

- Open the xcodeproject (in the ios subdirectory) in xcode

**General**

1. Change the Scheme to Release

   1. Go to Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme
   2. Select the Run Stage
   3. Select `Release` as Build Configuraiton
   4. Deselect `Debug executable`
2. Change the Target Device to `Generic iOS Device` (This is the field where you usually select the simulator your app should be run on)
3. Build/Archive your app (Click on Product>Archive)